# Append columns in file

Tags: file, fortran, append, multiple-columns

I am new to Fortran and have a question concerning read / write append(?) in Fortran:

I have 2 Files:
File1.dat  ( ASCII) that contains 4 columns:

```
1  10  1   5
2  20  5   8
3  30  76  8
...
```

File2.dat  ( ASCII) that contains 2 columns:

```
22   18
18   1
3    7
8    74
...
```

Now I want to create a new file and append the columns of File 2 to the right of the columns of file 1 ( Note that the number of rows can be different)

File3.dat (ASCII)

```
1  10  1   5   22   18
2  20  5   8   18   1
3  30  76  8   3    7
               8    74
...
```

I tried to do that with the OPEN READ and WRITE command, which worked with 1 File, but when I tried to use 2 Files at the same time to read from, it didn't work.

Is there a command in Fortran to append columns to files?

---

The problem is that my 2 files will sure have different number of rows. When I run my loop (in my example) 3 times, everything works well, when I run the loop more often, I get an Error:

```
list in: end of file
apparent state: unit 15 named File1.dat
last Format: list io
lately reading direct formatted external 10
```

Here is my code:

```
program addColumn
implicit none
real*4 a,b,c,d,e,f
integer*2  i

open (20, file='File3.dat', status='replace')
do i = 1, 3
  open(15, file='File1.dat')
  open(16, file='File2.dat')
  read(15, *) a,b,c,d
  read(16, *) e,f
  write (20,*) "row", i,":   ", a , b ,c ,d ,e ,f
  print *,     "row", i,":   ", a , b ,c ,d ,e ,f
end do
close(15)
close(16)
close(20)
end
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Don't use "it didn`t work" in questions. Not here and not anywhere else. It doesn't tell us anything useful. Did you get an error message? Which message? Was the result wrong? In which way it was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions that can prevent reading from multiple files simultaneously. Probably, you have to pay attention on file descriptors - they should be different for all files you are going to work with. Consider following example, it reads from two text files and writes to the third one at the same time.

```
program append_columns

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: iostat_end
    implicit none

    character(len=256) string1, string2
    character(len=16) format

    integer unit1, unit2, unit3
    integer status1, status2
    integer index, length

    open(newunit = unit1, file = 'column_file_1.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
    open(newunit = unit2, file = 'column_file_2.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
    open(newunit = unit3, file = 'column_file_result.txt', status = 'replace', action = 'write')
    do
        read(unit1, '(a)', iostat = status1) string1
        read(unit2, '(a)', iostat = status2) string2
        if ((status1 == iostat_end) .and. (status2 == iostat_end)) then
            exit
        end if

        if ((status1 > 0) .or. (status2 > 0)) then
            error stop 'Could not read a file.'
        end if

        !... some lines removed 
        write(unit3, format) trim(string1), trim(string2)

        !... some lines removed 
    end do

    close(unit1)
    close(unit2)
    close(unit3)
end
```